# Adding a button into Datatables // Open button to open another layout

Tags: laravel, datatables

I hope you are all safe during this time.

I am using DataTables in my web application. I have added an action column with a button Open that when clicked will open the Employee profile of that row. I have also added the JS but something is wrong as it does not open the route.

[JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3mIJ.png)

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTeqv.png)

[Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX4r4.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMwyd.png)

Comment: please add your codes as code not as image. however your route is missing parameter when rendering. use a constant as parameter and then replace it with original data.

Comment: Was writing it all wrong. Fixed the problem but thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the click event of class `.openEmployee` change the format of passing the user id in the `$.get()` method as below :

```
{{ route('employee.profile', user_id) }}
```

Comment: Did that, still get error: Use of undefined constant user_id - assumed 'user_id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: /Users/user/Desktop/DetyraSample/resources/views/employees/index.blade.php)

Comment: I think the issue is of not getting user_id or wrap the code of php into the JS properly.

Answer (score 0):

Error was when writing the action of the button at controller.
Below is how i got it to open the user profile when clicked.

[$btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmYCy.png)